# defun removes function in spacemacs config

Tags: spacemacs, variables, defun

I re-defined the function org-archive-subtree to call another function as described in the function below. I did this in spacemacs/user-config, now I can't call org-archive-subtree and C-h v (describe variable) can't find org-archive-subtree anymore. Why does the variable disappear?

`(defun org-archive-subtree ()
  (org-archive-subtree-hierarchical)
  )`

Everything I did is described in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35475878/5114384

Comment: What variable?  In Emacs 26.1 at any rate there is no `org-archive-subtree` variable in org-archive.el

Comment: Yes that is correct, it's not a variable at all so it won't show in describe variable. Running it gives the error "wrong type argument: commandp, org-archive-subtree"

Comment: A function is only a *command* if it contains an `(interactive)` form.  Only commands can be called with `M-x` or bound to keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I did not "remove" defun. You cant look up functions with `describe-variable`.
2. I solved it by adding this:

   (setq org-archive-default-command 'org-archive-subtree-hierarchical)

and using C-c C-x C-a instead of spacemacs defaults.

Comment: It looks like you've solved your problem. Please 'accept' your answer by clicking on the check mark. That will remove your question from the 'unanswered' list.